# Disneyland Discount on Paris Visite Pass?

Tags: paris, disney

On Paris Visite Pass, there is 20% discount on Disneyland 1 day/2 parks ticket. But if I purchase the ticket online how can I get the discounted ticket using the Paris Visite pass?

Answer (score 1):

I looked everywhere but couldn't find a really clear answer. I do think however, that you have to buy the ticket at the park and cannot buy online. [This source](http://www.disneylandparis.co.uk/parks-and-activities/disney-and-around/paris/paris-visite-travel-pass.html) for the same discount, but last year indicates:

> The Disney ticket money-off deal is until 7th November 2013 on presentation of a valid Paris Visit Travel Pass at the Disney Parks ticket desk.

I found the same for 2012, so it's probable it will still be the same now.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I am searching for this answer for so many days but didn't find any. I also emailed Disney land Official website and reply was that "We are unable to reply you regarding this" :P